# How to parse json list when the list's individual items are not of the same format using Retrofit and Gson?

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, retrofit

I am using `Retrofit` and `Gson` to communicate with server and parse responses.

I am receiving list of **geometry** objects list from server. But the coordinates field of the object might differ. For example, I am receving the following json from server:

```
{
  "geometry":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates": [
        76.95210456848145,
        43.2790799527603
    ]
  }
}
```

Sometimes this object returns me in this format:

```
{
  "geometry":{
   "type":"Polygon",
   "coordinates":[
       [
          [76.9478130340576,43.286265501840916],
          [76.9482421875,43.276267985142056],
          [76.95098876953125,43.27101863123778]
       ]
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, sometimes `coordinates` field is just a list (in the first example). Sometimes, this field is 3-level deep list (in the second example).

As a result of this, I cannot correctly parse the list since format of the elements in the list is not the same.

How can I correctly parse this?

Currently, I am using this data class:

```
data class Geometry(
    @SerializedName("coordinates")
    val coordinates: List<List<List<Double>>>,

    @SerializedName("type")
    val type: String)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you know that there are 2 versions of the file, create one inner class for each file. At time of parsing, identify the type of "coordinates" if it's the 1st type proceed with the 1st, if the second proceed with the second

```
inner class GeometryV2(
  @SerializedName("coordinates")
  val coordinates: List<List<List<Double>>>,

  @SerializedName("type")
  val type: String)
}
inner class GeometryV1(
  @SerializedName("coordinates")
  val coordinates: List<Double>,

  @SerializedName("type")
  val type: String)
}
```